# Symfony 2 - How to override templates out of app/Resources folder

Tags: php, symfony

Our Symfony project has moved the Resources directory from `app/Resources` to `src/Resources` - just to have everything at the same place.

It works fine, but the problem is with some vendor bundles and overriding templates. Some of them can be configured to look at different locations than app/Resources, but some seem to look only there and cannot be forced to do other than that.

**To be specific:** I need to create custom error templates. The documentation says it needs to be put into `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception`. When I try to put it into `src/AppBundle/Resources` or `src/TwigBundle`, it just doesn't work.

**Is there any way how to force Symfony to look into other paths by default?**

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: did you properly clear cache ?

Comment: What exactly did you make to move Resource directory? What have you redefined?

Comment: @Cerad Namespaced paths don't work when I try to override TwigBundle templates (the custom error pages). It just looks into the old app/Resources directory.

Comment: @singebatteur Yes, I cleared the cache several times.

Comment: Try harder.  Symfony uses namespaces to load bundle templates.  You can adjust the load paths accordingly.  I stopped using twig sometime ago but adjusting the paths was something I did regularly just to overcome this sort of nonsense.  Try dumping the search paths out to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom Controller for Exception which properly extends and return your own view from there. Take a look at [enter link description here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller)

Comment: Hmm, thanks, that seems like a solution for the error pages. But I will need to override templates from more bundles. So it would be nice if there is a universal solution how to tell Symfony and other bundles to look into a specific directory (namespaced paths don't work in this case, for example).

Comment: So you need to create a Bundle that extends TwigBundle and override templates but this is not checked solution.